# How to change the boot order of APFS volumes?

Tags: macos, apfs, dual-boot, beta

I recently set up a new APFS volume to support dual boot for the macOS Catalina beta alongside my Mojave install. Unfortunately, this new "beta OS" volume seems to have set itself up as the default boot volume.

How can I change the order of volumes so that the more stable OS takes priority?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer on my own:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Search for "Startup Disk"
3. Click the volume that you'd like to be the default